# Ошибка при добавлении dll из c++ в проект на c# (Не удается найти точку входа)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Добрый день!
Есть несколько простых функций на dll'ке с++ таких как add,substract,divide,
в проекте c# вызываю их таким образом:

```
[DllImport("MathFuncs.dll",EntryPoint="Add",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
[DllImport("MathFuncs.dll",EntryPoint="_Substract", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double Substract(double a, double b);
```

и на батоне соответственно вызываю функцию:

```
 c = Add(c, tmp);
```

Вопрос таков: при вызове Add все работает замечательно, но если вызывать другие функции вылезает ошибка: Не удается найти точку входа ...
В чем проблема?
при том если закоментить все функции и оставить одну любую (кроме add) то все равно такая ошибка.

Код на плюсах

```
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"

_declspec(dllexport)
double Sub(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
_declspec(dllexport)
double Add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
_declspec(dllexport)
double Multiply(double a, double b)
{
    return a*b;
}
_declspec(dllexport)
double Divide(double a, double b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
    return a / b;
}
```

И в хидере

```
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;


extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b); }
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double Sub(double a, double b); }
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b); }
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b); }
```

Comment: Такая ошибка характерна при ошибке в сигнатуре функции или в её название.

Comment: Без кода экспорта функций в плюсовом коде ответить на ваш вопрос затруднительно

Comment: Посмотрите имена экспортируемых из dll функций с помощью какого-нибудь DependencyWalker.

Comment: Обновил ответ. И еще Вам вопрос - что будет, если оставить только ```[DllImport(@"MathFuncs.dll")]``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, в коде библиотеке - юзается ли там `extern "C"` - если нет, то имена манглятся, и Ваша `Add` - совсем не `Add`.

UPD: выяснили, не из за этого. Тогда попытка помочь *номер 2*: добавьте `_stdcall`

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Add(double a, double b); }
```

Код:

```
// mathlib.h
#pragma once
extern "C" 
{ 
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Add( double, double ); 
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Sub( double, double ); 
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Mul( double, double ); 
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Div( double, double ); 
}

// mathlib.cpp
#include "mathlib.h"

__declspec(dllexport) 
double __stdcall Add( double lo, double ro)
{
    return ( lo + ro );
}

__declspec(dllexport) 
double __stdcall Sub( double lo, double ro )
{
    return ( lo - ro );
}

__declspec(dllexport) 
double __stdcall Mul( double lo, double ro )
{
    return ( lo * ro );
}

__declspec(dllexport) 
double __stdcall Div( double lo, double ro )
{
    return ( lo / ( ro == 0.0 ) ? 1.0 : ro );
}

// C# app
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace libconsm
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"mathlib.dll", EntryPoint ="Add", CallingConvention =CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

        [DllImport(@"mathlib.dll", EntryPoint = "Sub", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern double Sub(double a, double b);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(Add(12, 12));
            Console.Write(Sub(13, 12));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот, собственно. Только что проверил - все работает. Кст., Вы когда собираете - учитываете debug/release версию сборок ?

Результаты выполения комманды `dumpbin /exports`:

Release:
[image: Release]

Debug:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, они, различаются. Так что там в настройках при сборке .dll нужно шаманить, если что.

Comment: error C2373: 'Add' : redefinition; different type modifiers

Comment: @user230911, попробуйте прямо в хедере написать тело ф-ии. ```extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Add(double a, double b){...} }```

Comment: @user230911, кст., в .cpp файле тоже поправили - добавляли ```__stdcall```?

Comment: поменял в .cpp "не удается найти точку входа"

Comment: написал в хедере тело функции - ошибка прежняя

Comment: Оставил
[DllImport(@"MathFuncs.dll")]
заработало.
Спасибо

Comment: @user230911, сейчас я все сам перепроверю, извините, был на работе, так что не очень удобно было отвлекаться.

Comment: @user230911, судя по ```_Substract```, вариант с манглингом Вы до моего ответа проверили ?)

Comment: нет, не проверял, в конечной версии использую просто "Sub" и все ок.

Comment: @user230911, обновил ответ.

Comment: да, у меня все примерно так и получилось
debug/release не учитывал. Учел - все ок)
Спасибо!

Comment: @user230911, ну хорошо. Если я Вам помог - отметьте, пожалуйста, вопрос верным.

Comment: Вы бы указали какие команды консоли разработчика используете. И вроде же имена в левой части, и они одинаковые для Release/Debug.